# Long email go out of bound

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

[image: Profile Page Card]

[image: Code]

Here is the code:

```
<div className='mt-[3vh] flex h-1/3 min-h-fit w-[80%] min-w-[300px] flex-col content-center items-center justify-center  rounded-2xl bg-white shadow-[0_0_8px_rgba(0,0,0,0.2)]'>
      {user?.image && (
        <img
          src={user?.image}
          width={120}
          height={80}
          className='mt-[-60px] w-1/3 min-w-[120px] rounded-full'
          alt={`${user?.name}'s profile picture`}
        />
      )}
      <div className=' max  px-3 text-center'>
        <h3 className='my-5 text-4xl text-[24px] font-bold'>
          {user?.name}
        </h3>

        <h2 className='mb-[40px] text-2xl text-[16px]'>{email}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want to display that email on the card. It works fine for small email addresses, but when the email is too long, it will go out-of-bound. I tried tailwind CSS property truncate, but still, I am getting out-of-bounds emails.

How can I sort this out?

Comment: Please include your code as text and not as an image.

Comment: I have added code; please check and let me know what changes are required.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `overflow-****` with `max-w-****`, otherwise `overflow-****` didn't work.